# How can loop over two dictionaries at once?

Tags: python

How can I iterate through items of two dictionaries in a single loop? This is not working:

```
for word, cls in self.spam.items() and self.ham.items():
    pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

for word, cls in chain(self.spam.items(), self.ham.items()):
    print(word, cls)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since in Python2, `dict.items()` will generate a list of `(key,value)` tuples, you can concatenate the two lists, whereas in Python3, it will return a [viewing object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), hence we need to convert it to a `list`, so the following is also one way to do:

```
>>> d1 = {1:'ONE',2:'TWO'}
>>> d2 = {3:'THREE', 4:'FOUR'}
>>> dict_chained = d1.items() + d2.items() #Python2
>>> dict_chained = list(d1.items())+list(d2.items())) #Python3
>>> for x,y in dict_chained:
    print x,y


1 ONE
2 TWO
3 THREE
4 FOUR
>>>
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3 `dict.items()` returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), which doesn't support concatenation.

Comment: @eugeney .. thanks for the head's up...will update with more general solution